# Jquery Autocomplete show 2 lines for 1 item instead of cutting it off

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to use jQuery UI's autocomplete to show a bunch of strings from an array but some of these strings are quite long and because of that part of them go offscreen.

Now my question is how do I make it so that when one of my strings is too long that instead of it going offscreen it keeps going on a different line.

I've tried searching online a bit but I've had difficulty wording it correctly and can't find any solutions to my problem.

My code for my autocomplete is pretty simple:

```
JS
$("#myInput").autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: arrayOfStrings
});

HTML
<div class="ui-widget">
    <input type="text" id="myInput"/>
</div>
```

So to specify I want if a string is too long to fit on the screen to take up 2 lines instead just 1 cut of line so the entire string is readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marcos was close, but you will need to add the `white-space: pre-wrap;` to `.ui-menu .ui-menu-item-wrapper` to your CSS as shown below.  Type the letter "t" for a working example when running the demo of the code snippet.

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item-wrapper {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

See description of `white-space: pre-wrap` at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

```js
$( function() {
    var arrayOfStrings = [
        "This is a string",
        "This is another string",
        "This is a long string that should word wrap",
        "This is yet another that is long enough to word wrap",
        "This is a short string",
        "This is the last string"
    ];
    $("#myInput").autocomplete({
        minLength: 1,
        source: arrayOfStrings
    });
});
```

```css
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item-wrapper {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.ui-widget.ui-widget-content {
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <input type="text" id="myInput"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try in your css file with

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: The site is not online

Comment: I need to see generated div to apply correctly the CSS, if you upload to a ftp file I can help you